# The difference between [teaching] and [education]

Tags: discussion, tagging

> Update: [teaching](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/teaching) is now a synonym of [education](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/education).

While I think that [teaching](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/teaching) has a clear meaning, [education](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/education) could refer to teaching (doing the educating) or being/getting educated.  I'd suggest that the tag [teaching](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/teaching) be renamed [education-teaching](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/education-teaching) and that the questions tagged as [education](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/education) should be retagged as [education-teaching](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/education-teaching) or [education-learning](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/education-learning) as appropriate.  What do you think?

Comment: You agree that `teaching` has a clear meaning and it appears that it is being used correctly. Why, then, should the `teaching` tag be changed? Looking at existing questions, there are 3 questions tagged `education` but not `teaching`. Does this issue really confuse anyone?

Comment: Because I think it's very likely that someone tagging a question as `teaching` question will also tag it `education`, whereas if they were to type either and see the suggested `education-teaching`, I'd expect it to encourage them to use the one "correct" tag.  It's quite possible that I'm wrong about this, though.

Comment: I agree that this would help prevent people from tagging questions as both `education` and `teaching`. Can you provide an example of when this would be undesirable?

Comment: @Kaestur: If every question that was tagged with `education` that was about teaching also had the `teaching` tag, it wouldn't bother me, but having to sort through questions tagged `education` which cover two distinctly different meanings to get at questions on just one of those meanings mildly irritates me.  That is, my issue with the `education` tag is that it's ambiguous (like `algebra`), and I'd rather resolve it into two clearer tags early on (like `algebra-precalculus` and `abstract-algebra`).

Answer (score 8):

Four years later, this still isn't resolved: we have separate tags [education](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/education) (928 questions) and [teaching](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/teaching) (392 questions). At first glance, they look different because [education](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/education) would include learning as well as teaching. However, both tag wikis explicitly include teaching and learning:

> Mathematics education consists in the practice of teaching and learning mathematics, along with the associated research. Research in mathematics education concerns the tools, methods and approaches that facilitate the practice of mathematics or the study of this practice.

> Questions related to the teaching and learning of mathematics.

I see that the first also includes research in Mathematics Education; but such questions are actually rare on the site. They would be better asked at [Mathematics Educators](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/) anyway.

---

I propose to

#### Make [teaching](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/teaching) a synonym of [education](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/education)

Note that being a tag synonym is not the same as "synonymous" in ordinary language. Tag synonyms are not symmetric: rather, they mean that when a user tries to add tag A, tag B  is added instead.

Also,

#### Include a mention of [Mathematics Educators](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/) in the tag wiki

For example: "Some such questions may get a better answer at [Mathematics Educators](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/)".

Answer (score 3):

"pedagogy" seems clearer than either *teaching* or *education*.

Comment: I like "pedagogy."  I hadn't thought of that, which makes me a little worried about discoverability, as Grigory M put it, but that could probably be taken care of by making "teaching" and/or "education-teaching" synonyms of "pedagogy."  What about the learning aspect of education--suggestions for what to use for it?

Comment: As long as one principal tag is selected, retagging the "wrong guesses" by posters will have a synchronization effect, as anyone who sees or searches for words like *teach*, *education* will see queries with the pedagogy (or whatever the ultimate name) tag, and being subject-universal it would be one of the higher-ranked tags.   Anyway, these tags are often added as edits after the original question, not by the new users, so as long as there is some convention it will be followed.

Answer (score 2):

I am bumping this question to bring this discussion back to life. I am in favour of [T.'s suggestion](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/496/the-difference-between-teaching-and-education/500#500) that [teaching](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/teaching) and [education](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/education) be synonym-merged into [pedagogy](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pedagogy). Can people comment on whether that would be a desirable move?

Comment: I think this is a good decision.

Comment: I like this suggestion. Also [pedagogy] is a cooler tag than both [teaching] and [education].

Comment: I'm not so sure that this is a good idea. [education] has quite a few *requests* concerning how to *learn*, e.g. http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/50209/whats-wrong-with-me, http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/49406/mathematics-necessary-for-a-masters-degree-in-cs, http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/734/online-math-degree-programs, http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/40973/which-of-these-courses-to-take-if-one-intends-to-go-to-grad-school-in-pure-math (just to give a few random ones)

Comment: @Theo: maybe the main tag should be education then? Because there are also a lot of other mixes of things under education. Perhaps we can just subsume teaching as part of it?

Comment: Well, on looking again, (education) seems to be a random collection of just about everything, while the (teaching) tag seems to be quite consistent. Also, I might be alone with this view, but I see (teaching) and (pedagogy) not exactly as the same thing. I think I  prefer to have two separate tags (teaching) and (education).

Comment: As I'd said in the question, [tag:education] is a mix of [tag:teaching] and [tag:learning] (or things like those), so I don't think it's suitable to relabel all [tag:education] questions as [tag:pedagogy].  I wouldn't entirely mind [tag:teaching] being renamed to [tag:pedagogy], but I don't really see the point.

Comment: @Isaac Yeah (education) was the problem tag, and still is.

Comment: @MarkHurd: was this question autobumped recently somehow? Please note that this discussion is 3 years old.

Comment: @WillieWong No, I just noticed I was "preferred" in both in the [tag-future](http://math.stackexchange.com/users/tag-future/current) test feature. So it was a personal bump.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggests using `teaching` for... well, teaching and using `education` only in the second meaning. (But enforcing it will be quite a pain, I guess.)

Long tags like `education-teaching` lack *discoverability* — we'll have to explain *each* new user what does it mean.

Comment: I don't think discoverability is an issue at all--with the two tags that I suggested, typing "teaching" into the tag field will bring up only "education-teaching" as a suggestion and typing "education" will bring up both "education-teaching" and "education-learning" (try, e.g., typing "algebra" in the tag field on the main site).